# Swap: Better to create a dedicated swap partition or to create a swap file?

Tags: debian, swap

Is there a rationale when to create a dedicated swap partition vs. creating a swap file, for example like `/tmp/swap`?

In my certain case, memory is kind of low (1GB), disk space on a SSD is pretty huge (256GB). Thus, swapping will happen pretty regularly.

Any comments appreciated!

Carsten

Comment: Be aware you may shorten the lifespan of your SSD by using it for swap. http://askubuntu.com/questions/652337/why-no-swap-partitions-on-ssd-drives

Answer (score 5):

The main disadvantage that I can see for using swap files as opposed to swap partitions is that it's not possible to have a swap partition get fragmented, whereas it's possible that, upon creation, a swap file on an extent filesystem can get split up on the disk, causing slower sequential access.

Comment: Since SSD's don't have a random-read penalty there is very little harm from the fragmented file.

Comment: To be honest, I've been in favor for a swap partition ever since, but hey, as we say over here in Germany, "there is no cost in asking" ;-)

Comment: I'll often make swap files for temporary use if I foresee a large project coming that may exhaust the configured RAM and swap partitions, but I like to keep it partitioned.  That way, I can re-use swap partitions between Linux distributions just as readily as I can reuse home partitions.

Comment: The part about “more layers of kernel code to traverse when writing to a file on a filesystem” is not true: “*The kernel generates a map of swap offset -> disk blocks at swapon time and from then on uses that map to perform swap I/O directly against the underlying disk queue, bypassing all caching, metadata and filesystem code.*” – [Linux-Kernel Archive: Re: Swap partition vs swap file](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0507.0/1690.html)

Answer (score 4):

Access to swap files doesn't go through the filesystem ... the kernel knows which disk blocks are swap and accesses them directly<sup>1</sup>.  But a non-contiguous file may have fragments in different areas of the disk, and depending on the specific usage, additional seeking may make it slower than a dedicated partition.

OTOH, if you are dealing with a cloud server that has no swap partition and there is no possibility to create one, a swap file may save your application.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> “*The kernel generates a map of swap offset -> disk blocks at swapon time and from then on uses that map to perform swap I/O directly against the underlying disk queue, bypassing all caching, metadata and filesystem code.*” – [Linux-Kernel Archive: Re: Swap partition vs swap file](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0507.0/1690.html)

Comment: What is the case if the fs moves/resizes file blocks? I think in the case of the swap files, at least some fs driver interaction should exist.

Comment: Upvoted. This should be the accepted answer as it's the only one that states that the kernel directly accesses the disk blocks used for swap.

Answer (score 2):

I/O operations on a file have to go through more layers of kernel code (VFS for example), so there's more overhead associated with swapping to a file. On the other hand it's a more flexible setup and may be good enough for your case.

Comment: Perhaps I should get myself more familiar on Swap I/O pomp, ducks and circumstances... Isn't there anything about Linux just being nice, slow and simple?? ^^ :D

PS: Well, forget about the "slow" thing... ^^

Comment: That's not actually true: “*The kernel generates a map of swap offset -> disk blocks at swapon time and from then on uses that map to perform swap I/O directly against the underlying disk queue, bypassing all caching, metadata and filesystem code.*” – [Linux-Kernel Archive: Re: Swap partition vs swap file](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0507.0/1690.html)

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, swap files are relatively efficient, if the swap file is allocated as a contiguous set of blocks (important to either create it at the beginning or defragment the filesystem before creation to enable this), then it's almost as efficient as a partition.

Even using it combined with ephemeral encryption (very important for security) doesn't add much overhead (see the `crypttab` manual page).